# T shaped divider in LaTeX by using multicols

Tags: pdf, format, latex, pdflatex, multicol

[image: T shaped seperators are not connecting]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 total={272mm,394mm},
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm
 }
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.3mm}

\title{Test}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2}
[
\flushleft{\rule{176mm}{0.3mm}}
]

\blindtext[10]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I have tried to make a 'T' shaped divider for a document, but it seems like multicols doesn't support a horizontal line above the columns.

I tried to simulate this effect by using

```
\flushleft{\rule{176mm}{0.3mm}}
```

but this doesn't help me out.

Is there any way to erase the gap between the two dividers? or is there a different way to make a 'T' shaped divider?

Also, im curious why the the horizontal length of the \rule is 176mm. the width of the paper is 272mm and the margins in the left and right are 20mm each, so why is the length 176mm instead of 232mm?

Comment: "the width of the paper is 272mm", no it is not. The paper is still the default size, e.g. letter or a4paper. With your `total` key you are merely setting the size of the text block and then immediately overwrite it by setting your margins separately. A warning in the log file will tell you about the over specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place your horizontal line before the multicols:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
% total={272mm,394mm},
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm
 }
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.3mm}

\title{Test}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.3mm}

\vspace*{-0.5cm}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext[10]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]